# Rxjs Observable is not updating value correctly

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, behaviorsubject

Inside a service which stores the state of a user shoppingcart I have a BehaviorSubject of an Array. This array contains Items that the user has put in his shoppingcart. Each ordered item inside this array contains the quantity, baseprice and the current price (quantity * baseprice).

The user can change the quantity of each item with a +/- button. The State in the BehaviorSubject gets updated according to the selected quantity.

`private orderedProducts = new BehaviorSubject<OrderItem[]>([]);`

I have writte a method to calculate the current order sum based on the BehaviorSubject like this:

```
getOrderSum$(): Observable<number> {
  return this.orderedProducts$.pipe(
    map((orderItems) => orderItems.reduce((accTotal, orderItem) => accTotal + (orderItem.currentPrice), 0)),
    tap((price) => console.log('Current Order Sum', price)));
}
```

I subscribe to this Observable in different parts of the appliction with the `async` Pipe.
On the firtst subscribe of the stream, the observable behaves as I expected. The `tap` Operator logs the correct value once and my UI refreshes accordingly.

If I now navigate to a different part of the app (order overview) where I also subscribed with the `async` Pipe, two values get logged when the user changs the quantity of an item (using +/- button): the current (correct) order sum and then immidiatly after that the old (incorrect) order sum.

I tried to manually subscribe calling the `.subscribe()` method and then manually unsubscribing from it when the component gets destroyed. This didnt solve the problem and from my understanding the `async`pipe handles automatic sub/unsubbing from observables. Thats why I dont really understand why the value gets logged twice when navigating to the other component and why it always displays the old value.

Additional Info:
The serivce is injected using `provideIn: root`.

The method that updates the quantity of ordered Items finds the item with the correct ID and then changes the quantity. The new array gets emitted on the BehaviorSubject :

```
 updateQuantityOfOrderItem(orderItem: OrderItem, quant: number) {
    if (quant >= 1) {
      this.orderedProducts.pipe(
        mergeMap((items) => items),
        filter((itemProd) => itemProd.id === orderItem.id),
        map((item) => {
          item.quantity = quant;
          item.orderItemPrice = item.product.basePrice * quant;
        }),
        distinctUntilChanged()).subscribe(() => this.orderedProducts.next([...this.orderedProducts.value]));
    } else {
      //Delete Product
      this.orderedProducts.pipe(
        take(1),
        map((prod) => prod.filter(p => p.id !== orderItem.id)))
        .subscribe(this.orderedProducts.next.bind(this.orderedProducts));
    }
  }
```

This all works as expected in one component. But when I subscribe to the value in another component on another page the value isnt updated until I completly delete a product from the cart (quantity = 0). Then the value changes to the correct value and doesnt change anymore.

What I dont understand is that when I change the quantity of an item on the page where the calculation isnt working and then navigate back to the other page where it is working. The correct updated value is displayed.

Comment: You are correct in `async` pipeline taking care of (un)subscribing automatically. Can you show us how you provided/injected the service in question? I assume you have multiple instances of the service running, hence the difference in output.

Comment: sounds like first component with async pipe is not getting destroyed, hence it continues to run

Comment: How is the `OrderedProductsService` provided?

Comment: @PhilippMeissner I inject the service in the constructor of the component like this  `constructor(private orderedProductsService: OrderedProductsService) {}` The service is annotated with provideIn: root so I thought that it gets instatiated as a singleton.

Comment: @AndrewAllen I tried implementing the ngOnDestroy() Method and indeed the component isnt destroyed when navigating to a different page. But shouldnt the Service emit the correct value regardless of its subscribers when it gets instatiated as Signleton (prodvided In root) ?

Comment: would need to see code. i.e how is `orderedProducts$` managed, is component that isn't destroyed emitting old copy of array, for example

Comment: I did some quick research and found that the component only gets destroyed when calling `{replaceUrl: true}` in the `navigateByUrl` method. This however didnt fix the issue. I am adding some additianal info to the question